# google custom search root annotations file

Tags: annotations, hosting, google-custom-search

I have created a root annotations file which does reference an annotations file. But all annotations are ignored. If I include the annotations in the root annotation file everything works fine.

The root annotation file:

```
*<GoogleCustomizations>
    <Include type="Annotations" href="http://myhost.net/System/GoogleCustomSearch/SozialversicherungAnnotationsSiteList.xml" 
</GoogleCustomizations>*
```

The annotations file:

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Annotations>
    <Annotation about="http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch">
        <Label name="_cse_xyxyxyxyxyx"/>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>*
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm trying to tell google to get the annotations from a file hosted on my site but I was not successful. If you solved your problem can you tell me how?

Comment: With the help of the excellent Google support I could solve my problem.

Comment: With the help of the excellent Google support I could solve my problem. The solution is: 1. Upload the root annotations file under the section "**Annotations-Feeds**" and not under the section "CSE-Annotations". 2. Wait up to 72 hours until the changes work. 3. If you want to search a whole website, don't forget to add the wildcard character (e.g. "www.tagesanzeiger.ch/*" and not just "www.tagesanzeiger.ch").

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem when I read the instructions found at [Linked Custom Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/linked_cse)

You have to include the link to your xml file hosted on your site in the CSE url with the cref param and remove the cx param as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the excellent Google support I could solve my problem. The solution is:

1. Upload the root annotations file under the section "**Annotations-Feeds**" and not under the section "CSE-Annotations". (The root annotations file and the referenced annotations file as shown in my question are correct.)
2. **Wait** up to 72 hours until the changes work.
3. If you want to search a whole website, don't forget to add the wildcard character (e.g. "www.tagesanzeiger.ch/*" and not just "www.tagesanzeiger.ch").